# DataTemplate doesn't work when moved to ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I was trying to move a DataTemplate from a ListView into a resource dictionary and it somehow broke the Bindings, I believe.

I verified that when I hardcode the Textblock text it displays in the listview and it seems the listview datasource binding is working, it just can't display my data.

Here's the Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="Marathon.Resources.ListViewTemplate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Marathon">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LVTemplate" x:DataType="local:Result">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Padding="12" AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind ID}">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ToString()}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="24"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here's how I'm referencing the template:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind VM.Results}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LVTemplate}" Background="#FF343434" >           
</ListView>
```

And Here's what it looks like when I have it inside the listview template instead of the dictionary:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind VM.Results}" Background="#FF343434" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Result">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Padding="12" AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind ID}">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ToString()}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="24"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here's screenshots of it working when not in the ResourceDictionary:
[image]

And here's it not working:
[image]

Edit:
Here's my App.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Marathon.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Marathon">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/VCenterTextBox.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/KeypadButton.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ListViewTemplate.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Comment: How about you try to add a Property with Get that will do the same what ToString() does? Maybe there's some problem with binding to a method, like it's called, the result is empty, then the list might be filled with items, but a method isn't called again so there are no results. Try writing your own Property that will call PropertyChanged when there is some data to display. Just my another approach to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `x:Bind` inside a `ResourceDictionary`, you'll need to declare the dictionary `partial` and create a code-behind file to instantiate it:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="Marathon.Resources.ListViewTemplate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Marathon">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LVTemplate" x:DataType="local:Result">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Padding="12" AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind ID}">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ToString()}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="24"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Code-behind:
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

```
namespace Marathon.Resources
{
  public partial class ListViewTemplate
  {
    public ListViewTemplate()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

App.xaml:

Hint: It is important to **instantiate the template like an object**, so that the partial class's constructor and the "InitializeComponent()" gets invoked. The point is that `x:Bind` is not resolved by the XAML engine at runtime, but by the compiler. That's what makes `x:Bind` more efficient.

To reference the resource, don't merge the file. Create an instance of the partial class (to trigger the compiler).

```
<Application
    x:Class="Marathon.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Marathon">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>               
                <local:ListViewTemplate />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

[Resource dictionaries with {x:Bind}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#resource-dictionaries-with-xbind)

Comment: Already doing that as well :/ Intellisense gives an error on X:Bind if you don't add the code-behind, thanks for the response though.

Comment: Please take a look how the ResourceDictionary is referenced. 
Use: "<local:ListViewTemplate"/>" 
instead of "<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ListViewTemplate.xaml"/>".

You have to instantiate the dictionary like an object so that the "InitializeComponent()" of the partial class is called

Comment: Don't reference the file.

Comment: I was having 1 week ago the same problem and I already solved it with this method.  Was going to post the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to add reference in you App.xaml then you can use your DataTemplate everywhere in your app.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Path/To/Your/ResourceFile/ListViewDataTemplate.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Another/Path/To/Your/ResourceFile/EGButtonTemplateStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I already had that in my App.xaml. I'm about to update my post with it.

Comment: Also, I don't get any errors from intellisense or during runtime, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @superzilla Are you changing your TextBlock Style in the runtime? If not, you might Change your ThemeResource to StaticResource and it might solve your problem

Comment: I don't believe I am. I based my DataTemplate off of one I saw on msdn where they used that ThemeResource. I just tried changing it to a StaticResource and removing the Style property from the Template and no change - still nothing displaying.